# How to combine two geometries into one plot in Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, geometry, projection

Question background: I am trying to make two geometries in a one plot in python. I have made one geometry which is an object having mesh as shown in figure below. The respective code is also mentioned here.

```
df_1_new = pd.DataFrame()
df_1_new['X_coordinate']=pd.Series(x_new)
df_1_new['Y_coordinate']=pd.Series(y_new)
df_1_new['node_number'] = df_1_new.index
df_1_new = df_1_new[['node_number','X_coordinate','Y_coordinate']]

plt.scatter(x_new, y_new)
plt.show
```

[image]

The second geometry, which is a circle and I made this geometry running below code.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, patches
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [9.00, 6.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
circle1 = plt.Circle((2, 2), radius=5, fill = False)
ax.add_patch(circle1)
ax.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

My question: How can I combine both geometries mentioned above in a one plot. I would like to place my circle around my geometry (object). Geometry has a centroid (2, 2) and I want to place my circle's centroid exactly on the centroid of geometry therefore I will be having a circle around my geometry. What code I should write. Kindly help me on this.

For your reference: I want my plot just like in below picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do all the plotting between the subplot creation and before you issue the `plt.show()` command, as any command after it will create a new figure.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, patches
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [9.00, 6.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
# other plt.scatter or plt.plot here
plt.scatter([3,4,5,6,4],[5,4,2,3,2]) # example
circle1 = plt.Circle((2, 2), radius=5, fill = False)
ax.add_patch(circle1)
ax.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIIfD.png)

to get the points inside the circle, you need to play with the circle radius and center till you get it right.

something you can do is to make the circle at the [`np.median`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.median.html) of your x and y values, so you are sure about the center position.

Comment: Thank you very much for guiding me on my problem. I think by mistake I wrote centre of geometry (2,2), but it is actually (0, 0) after shifting a geometry. But Yes, this code works well for me. Thank you again.

Comment: One more question I would like to ask. How can I divide the circle formed around the geometry into 36 equal parts or pixel? The reason behind this question: I want to project the nodes (X and Y coordinates) into the pixel of circle and at the end, want to make the vector by flattening the circle.

Comment: the answer for this is either too easy or too hard, if you want to make 36 squares that include the circle, then you can take the maximum and minimum value of both x and y and divide the difference by 6 to get the width and height of each square, then compute the center of each square that is equal to `min(x) + (row+0.5)*width` and `min(y) + (column+0.5)*height`, and to determine the square a point belongs to you just get the distance between it and all centers and pick the center with the least distance, if you meant that the 36 squares are inside the circle then that's a much harder problem.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. I would like to inform you that I want to make 36 equal parts of circumference (circular line above the geometry). If your last answer relavent to this question then I could not understand how we can find the height and width of the one sqaure box and why we need to divide the difference of Max and Min value of X and Y to 6?